# Manage Multiple Local Group Policy objects (GPO) with Microsoft Security Compliance Manager (SCM)?

Tags: group-policy, scm, mdt-2012

Is it possible to manage Multiple Local Group Policy objects (LGPO) with Microsoft Security Compliance Manager (SCM)? Specifically, I want to create different a LGPO for non-administrators. These are for laptops not on the domain.

I'm open to alternative suggestions. We are using Microsoft Deployment Toolkit to configure the laptops.